# What's difference between Watt Electric ($\rm We$) and Watt ($\rm W)$?

Tags: power, electronics, si-units, electrical-engineering

So, I'm learning about Radioisotope Thermoelectric Generator (RTG), and wherever I read about it (in websites, in textbook [Fundamentals of Nuclear Science and Engineering]), the unit used for its power is Watt electron (We). Those sources don't explain what We is. I tried searching on google, but the keywords never worked (always go to Watt pages again and its brothers kWh MW), even wikipedia never mentioned We as a unit. I know We and W are different right? What's the conversion between We and W? Or are they actually the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

For a device like a thermoelectric generator, it will have two ratings: 1) how much radioactive decay *heat* it releases in *watts*, and 2) its net electrical output in *watts* (electrical, as in volts x amperes).

You obtain the watts (electrical) by multiplying the heat watts by the *device efficiency* in per cent.

Thermoelectric generators have extremely low efficiencies, so it takes a lot of heat flux to generate just a few watts of electrical output.